# how to access client application (Scanner or .exe) which are installed on client machine using Asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, c#-4.0, barcode-scanner

how to access client application (Scanner or .exe) which are installed on client machine using Asp.net web application

I want to Access Scanner which are installed on client machine... I'm using a Asp.net Web Application With C# language....

The end users scan the images and then, The Scanned images should be stored on Server directory....

So, Please help regarding , How to Access the client side installed Scanner software... (because end users installed different types of Scanners may be HP,dell, Samsung)....

Comment: You might not write your phone number and e-mail address like that because there are a lot of spammers.

Comment: oh.... i didnt notice...

Answer (score 0):

You can start a exe from web page use 'user protocol', but I don't know their is a way to access local resources of client, I think you should consider to use flash or silverlight to do that.

Comment: I'm having a .exe file of my own. how to use in User Protocol / in web application ?

Comment: sorry for my mistake, it should be called "url protocol", you can check the detail from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx